# how can you update only newly added repo

Tags: apt, 18.04

if i add `add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php` how can i just updated to pull the info from the new repo? I don't want to do `apt update` and get an update from all of the repo's installed. I just want to pull in the fresh data from the newly added repo.

is that possible?

Comment: You can't, it's all or nothing.